# Should mathematics be the starting point of theoretical physics research or should it follow to support the hypothesis or experimental result?

Tags: black-holes, education, mathematics

In the supplied [link](https://www.livescience.com/black-holes-press-out-on-universe), mathematical analysis was used to suggest that black holes exert some amount of pressure.

Should mathematics be the starting point of theoretical physics/astrophysics research, or should it follow to support the hypothesis or experimental result?

Comment: I don't see how this can be anything other than a matter of opinion. You will find physicists who support both sides of the argument.

Comment: Mathematics should be a fundament of any scientific statement.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/jan/09/are-we-witnessing-the-dawn-of-post-theory-science

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematics by itself cannot lead to a physical conclusion. For this assumptions are required that connect the mathematical objects to the physical world.

Comment: @safesphere what pseudoscience? Black holes have been observed experimentally.

Comment: Another example where mathematics jumps ahead of observations is usage of Einstein's equations in interpretation of received/registered gravitational waves as being the result of collision/merge between two massive black holes (or collision/merge between massive black hole and neutron star).

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/jan/09/are-we-witnessing-the-dawn-of-post-theory-science